# How do I simulate a receiving antenna in EZNEC simulation tool?

Tags: antenna-construction, propagation, wire-antenna, wifi, antenna-modeling

I have a situation where I need to find receiving antenna impedance when it’s $\lambda/2$ distance from the transmitting antenna. Both are dipole antennas. Is it possible with EZNEC?

Comment: Are you worried about the interaction between the conductors of the receiving antenna and the transmitting antenna that is $\lambda/2$ distance?  I certainly wouldn't.  Usually, the receiving antenna impedance is not as critical as transmitting since a mismatch in transmitting affects power out and also potential harm to the transmitter or at least limiting power out by transmitter protection circuits.  Most receivers have "antenna trimmer" capacitors to improve the match with the antenna.

Comment: I want to find both 1.  Impedance change in the transmitter 2. Impedance of the receiver so that I can design a matching circuit between receiving antenna and rectifier.

Comment: OK, what you just said makes no sense to me.  Maybe you are attempting to do something totally different than things common to ham radio.  Maybe you can describe the goal of your question.

Comment: May be this might helps you. 
 
I want to find both 1. Impedance change in the transmitter when a receiving antenna is $lambda/2$ distance away from transmitter 2. Impedance of the receiver so that I can design a matching circuit between receiving antenna and rectifier

Comment: That is the same thing you said above.  Questions: (1) do you mean transmitter or transmitting antenna.  What is the purpose of the rectifier and where is it located?  Or, are you using the correct word?  When I ask what you are trying to do, I didn't mean the the details above of your question.  I meant why do you even care to know this stuff?  Are you planning to actively receive on one antenna while transmitting on the other?  Or, are you merely concerned about impedance change due to nearby conductor?  And, for a nearby conductor's impact on impedance it does not matter what you use it for

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant transmitting antenna impedance. Receiving antenna is part of rectenna. Rectenna is positioned such that its antenna is $\lambda/2$ distance away  from the transmitting antenna. Since I am harvesting within near field, impedance of receiving antenna may not be 73 ohms as wave impedance is not 377 ohms in near field.
I would like to simulate with EZNEC. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible.  Model your receiving antenna and transmitting antenna but apply the feed point to your receiving antenna and not the transmitting antenna.  This is because impedance is measured at the feed point location.  The transmitting antenna merely looks like conductors 1/2 wavelength away.  In your antenna model, you model all of the conductors meaning all metal parts of both TX and RX antennas.   Note that EZNEC is merely a front-end to NEC2 (or, NEC4) so you model per the NEC2 restrictions and limitations.  It is essentially a wire antenna modeling system.

Comment: Note:  If your TX antenna is a dipole, model it as a single wire which is the normal approach with NEC unless you are including changes to conductors or changes to elevation.  You DO NOT model a break for a feed point.  NEC automatically inserts a break at the middle of the segment (numbered) which you select when identifying the feed point location.  Since your TX antenna will not have a feed point you will not have a break in the conductor.  This will not affect your impedance calculation for the RX antenna.

Comment: That means, if I create a wire with 11/9 segments with no feed point as a transmitter, would that be enough? Of course, there is a feed point for the receiver.

Comment: Yes.  Also, experiment with the design a little bit.  For straight wire antennas, the segment count is usually not too critical.  As an example experimenting, I once modeled my dipole, which at the time was over the top of my house, by modeling as much of the house wiring as feasible (single wire lengths that ran the major distances parallel to antenna conductors).  Yes, I did find that this affected the radiation pattern but not in a significant way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is the effect of mutual coupling of the antennas. That, I believe, can be done in EZNEC by modeling both antennas at the same time (for example the transmitting antenna in the normal way and the receive antenna as a parasitic element not connected to anything).